# VS Code Support to "go to definition" (open file) when click on paths

Tags: visual-studio-code, twig, vscode-extensions

When using VS Code, one can simply Ctrl + click a Variable, function name or path to go to its definition. Sadly I cannot make this work for Twig files.

Is there any VS Code extension that enables "go to definition" functionality on Twig files, specially on the string in following example?

```
{% include 'components/bodytext.html.twig' with {
    text: bodytext
} only %}
```

I have tried multiple VS Code extensions with no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code, format HTML code with Twig or Swig tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866270/vs-code-format-html-code-with-twig-or-swig-tags)

Comment: No, sadly it doesn't.